# Unroll nested list of strings and save as .txt

Tags: python, list

I have a list with string elements:

```
[['110,67,169,86,5'], ['421,404,323,187,5'], ['865,98,452,53,2']]
```

which I want to write to a .txt file in one line as:

```
110,67,169,86,5 421,404,323,187,5 865,98,452,53,2
```

thanks for any help with this!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is correct:

```
>>> a = [['110,67,169,86,5'], ['421,404,323,187,5'], ['865,98,452,53,2']]
>>> " ".join([x[0] for x in a])
'110,67,169,86,5 421,404,323,187,5 865,98,452,53,2'
```

Comment: Thanks Lante, but the three list elements shouldn't be separated by a comma in the output - just a space...

Comment: edited. If you are interested read about `join` and list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Unroll your values and join them into one string

```
x = [['110,67,169,86,5'], ['421,404,323,187,5'], ['865,98,452,53,2']]
joined = ' '.join(sum(x, []))
# -> '110,67,169,86,5 421,404,323,187,5 865,98,452,53,2'
```

Save result to file

```
file = open('unrolled.txt', 'w')
file.write(joined)
file.close()
```